# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'audio_service' not found /Users/aleferafael/vida_plena/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having the problem mentioned above, I saw many people saying that the problem is solved by running the project in "Runner.xcworkspace", but I did that and it didn't solve it.

```
  #if __has_include(<audio_service/AudioServicePlugin.h>)
#import <audio_service/AudioServicePlugin.h>
#else
@import audio_service;
#endif
```